# How do I initialize the most minimum value inserted in a binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble figuring out how to set a variable "minData" to the minimum value inserted into a binary search tree. If I am thinking of this correctly, the most minimum value in the tree will always be in the left subtree so my code for setting this minimum value should go under the "else if (root.data < data)" statement. I also don't know how to access the minData variable inside my insert method. My code so far is:

```
private class Node {
    int key;
    int data;
    int minData;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Node root;
        Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        root = null;
        }
}

public TheBST(Node root) {
root = null;
}

public void insert(Node root, int data) {
Node newNode = new Node(data);   
    if(root == null) {
    Node node = new Node(data);
    root = node;
    }
    else if(root.data > data) {
        if(root.left == null) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        root.left = node;           
        }
    insert(root.left, data);
    }
    else if(root.data < data) {
        if(root.right == null) {
        Node node = new Node(data);
        root.right = node;
        return;
        }
    insert(root.right, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Handling insert is easy.  Just track the minimum inserted so far by comparing each new key with the current minimum in each node as the insertion algorithm traverses a path to the insert location.   The slightly tricky bit is handling deletion. As you say, the minimum in a BST is always the leftmost child of the root. So when that value is deleted, the minData for all right ancestors need to be updated with the  new leftmost child. A nice exercise. Btw, your insert algorithm is broken.  It keeps trying to insert even after the insertion is complete. Recursion for BST insert is not smart.

Answer (score 0):

Your forming of BST is not accurately done. You need to return from the method *(or stack fragment of memory in case recursive procedure)* when you would actually find the place to insert.

Add the return statement for the left-subtree:

```
 else if(root.data > data) {
      if(root.left == null) {
           Node node = new Node(data);
           root.left = node;           
           return;
        }
    insert(root.left, data);
 }
```

Which is you are doing in case of the right-subtree.

P.S: once you are done with tree insertion, you can return the left-most-node from left-subtree, it would have the minimum value.